# Exponential Function with "wrong" Plot in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

While experimenting with PGFPlots, I found out a little weird issue:

I want to plot the function given by `f(x) = 2^x`, so I type:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[   axis x line = center,
                        axis y line = center,
                        xmin = 0,
                        xmax = 4,
                        xlabel = {$x$},
                        ylabel = {$y$},
                        ticks = none,
                        width=6cm]

            \addplot[   smooth,
                        domain = 0:3]
                plot (\x,{2^(\x)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Which results in:
[image]

At first, I am happy the code works but upon a closer look, I realize that PGF says `f(0)= 2^0 = 0`, which is obviously wrong, as it should be 1. I tried to play with the parenthesis in the line:

```
    plot (\x,{2^(\x)});
```

But it didn't work. What could be causing this? I have suspected that it's some kind of scaling issue (as if the plot was zoomed out a lot), since I used the `width=6cm` option, but removing that doesn't seem to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: put the ticks back on and you'll see and then add `ymin=0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As percusse already mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299772/exponential-function-with-wrong-plot-in-pgfplots#comment725747_299772) this is because of the combination of options you have (not) used, i.e. providing `ticks=none` but not setting `ymin`. Turning back on the `ticks` and/or setting `ymin` will show you, that PGFPlots calculates the right values.

Also I want to note that you can simplify the equation you give to the `\addplot` handler. "Your version" is mainly used for parametric plots.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=0,         % <-- added
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
%           ticks = none,
            smooth,
            domain=0:3,
        ]
        % original version
            \addplot []                          (\x,{2^(\x)});
        % simplified version
            \addplot+ [only marks,mark size=1pt] {2^x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: `plot` is also not needed

Comment: @percusse, of course. I think I never use the "normal plot" handler, so I just forgot ;). Many thanks for the hint. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm really new to `PGFPlots`, so I wasn't aware these options were necessary to better build the plot. One question about your simplified version: What does the `+` after `\addplot` do? Also, why are you using `[only marks, mark size = 1pt]`?

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas, the `+` says that the following options should be __appended__ to the default style of this plot; that is why for example the color is still red. Otherwise only the applied options are used for the plot. I added the options so that for that plot no line is drawn between the points (`only marks`) and I set the size of the markers, as the name suggests.

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas, if you are new to PGFPlots, I suggest reading/doing the tutorials (see [chapter 3 in the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=16)). There you will learn a lot of the basics. Have fun !!